# Using timers in swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am a complete beginner and am starting to learn the Swift programming language. I'm following a tutorial on Udemy and am having some problems with setting up a timer.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
@IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!
var timer1 = Timer()
var counter = 0


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    label.text = String(counter)



}
@IBAction func start(_ sender: Any) {

    timer1 = Timer(timeInterval: 1, target: self, selector: #selector(tim), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)



}

@IBAction func pause(_ sender: Any) {

    timer1.invalidate()

}

@IBAction func restart(_ sender: Any) {

    timer1.invalidate()
    counter = 0
    label.text = String(counter)

}

@objc func tim() {

    counter += 1
    label.text = String(counter)

}
```

}

This is my code but the timer is not working. Please tell me where im going wrong.

Comment: What does “not working” mean? Be specific. What do you do and what happens as a result?

Comment: You have to add the timer to the runloop or use the `scheduledTimer` API. And *restart* resets the counter but doesn't restart the timer.

Comment: @matt the timer wouldn't start, but it looks like I wasn't scheduling it. it's all clear now!

Comment: @vadian Yes I got it thank you!

Comment: Were your running in the simulator when the problem occurred?

Comment: @benc thank you for reaching out, yes it was during that, however, the problem has already been solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add timer to `RunLoop`

```
RunLoop.current.add(timer1, forMode: .commonModes)
```

Or use `scheduledTimer`

```
timer1 = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1, target: self, selector: #selector(tim), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
```

Also in your `restart` function you need to do it again, because now you are just invalidating it and not starting again.

Comment: Thank you very much! Looks like I missed that. The restart function was intended as more of a reset. bad wording on my end.